# Why does bionic now freeze during LUKS boot?

Tags: boot, 18.04, luks

Recently I installed 18.04 on a clean M.2 form-factor SSD, in my Dell latitude E7470 laptop, enabling full-disk encryption.

For a week or two it worked fine, but since yesterday morning, I have not been able to boot normally:

If I let the system boot as usual, after I enter my LUKS passphrase, it seems to freeze for a while, then shows me some boot messages, including a failure: "Failed to start Create Static Device Nodes in /dev". It continues for a bit, then freezes, without my reaching the X login screen.

If I select the recovery option in the grub menu, after I enter my password the LUKS partition is available. If I choose to continue at the recovery menu, the system starts up, and I get an X prompt. However, certain hardware hasn't been initialised, so support for multiple monitors and wifi (among other things) appear not be working correctly.

I have tried booting from USB, and I can mount the LUKS partition fine, and then mount the LVM2 logical volume. fsck does not return any errors.

I do not see any evidence of disk corruption after logging in via the recovery menu. I have tried "update-initramfs", but that has not made a difference.

What can I try next? I will attach a couple of photos; I don't know how to capture the log messages properly since the system hangs during boot.

[photo of boot message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4Bi.jpg)

Comment: You can use journalctl -b to display the last boot log (journalctl -b > logfile.log should create a file).

Comment: What does *systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev* show?

Comment: Thanks for both of these suggestions. They were both helpful in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of my problem was that somehow the root partition (/) was no longer owned by the root user, which led to various sanity checks failing during boot.

Using the suggestions in the comments above helped me see other error messages which were slightly more relevant , and which by googling showed me other people in a similar situation.

I am not sure how the root partition had its owner changed but the solution was simply:

$ chown root /

After booting into recovery mode and opening a console